# moment.js how to use

Tags: javascript, html

I installed **min.js 11.6k gz** and I'm using it right now, it works almost as it should.

I got below code from tutorial which didn't explain indepth...

I want for it to show my website viewers how long ago I added something to the website, but the code I got when I run it, it shows me **"16 hours ago"** it is somehow starting from whatever time I got showing locally and counting from there instead of starting from 0.

I want to be able to input a date like 2015-01-23 in a div and moment.js should use that date as reference. I've tried, i searched youtube and this site and google and there are a lot of topics on it, but nothing I can understand. 
thanks

```
 <h2>Moment Date</h2>
<!-- container for Moment.js output -->
<div id="displayMoment"></div>


     <script type="text/javascript">
// use Moment.js to display current date in a div (#displayMoment)
var NowMoment = moment();
var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('displayMoment');
eDisplayMoment.innerHTML = NowMoment.startOf('hour').fromNow();      
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moment command you are looking for is:

```
moment("2014-12-20", "YYYY-MM-DD").fromNow(); // gives "2 months ago"
```

[Demo without reading div for date](http://jsfiddle.net/c4qaem0a/1/)

[Demo with input div](http://jsfiddle.net/9dgv1tmj/1/)

Comment: Beautiful thanks, i really appreciate it precisely what I needed, btw is there anyway to also input hour, minute and second? Like "YYYY-MM-DD-Hour-Minute-Second"?

Comment: @JackRebuilt should just be using ```"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"``` as the data format string instead of ```"YYYY-MM-DD"```

Comment: You've saved my life, thanks once again I really appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 1):

There are examples at http://momentjs.com/docs/ you can see all the different ways you can use to show the date and time that has passed.

For time it can be done as:

```
"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
```